# Save file on server using powershell

Tags: c#, powershell, file

I am trying to create xml file in C# and save that newly created file in local machine using powershell. new file is created at local but content is not saved.

I am creating simple xml file in C# as follows

```
XDocument doc = new XDocument(new XElement("body",
                                       new XElement("level1",
                                           new XElement("level2", "text"),
                                           new XElement("level2", "other text"))));
```

and I am passing "doc" as parameter to powershell script and invoke powershell as follows

```
Dictionary<string, XDocument> parameters = new Dictionary<string, XDocument>() { { "VMConfigFile", doc } };
powershell.AddCommand("PowershellFunc").AddParameters(parameters);
Collection<PSObject> results = powershell.Invoke();
Collection<ErrorRecord> errors = powershell.Streams.Error.ReadAll();
```

powershell function as

```
function PowershellFunc
{
  [CmdletBinding()]
  Param
  (
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true, 
                Position=0,
                HelpMessage='Please Provide Config File')]
    [ValidateNotNullOrEmpty()]
    [xml]$VMConfigFile
  )

  try
  { 
    $txt = $VMConfigFile
    $Session = New-PSSession 127.0.0.1
    Invoke-Command -Session $Session -ScriptBlock { Param($Txt) New-Item -Path c:\test\newFile.xml -Value $txt }  -ArgumentList $txt 
    #Get-PSSession | Remove-PSSession
    Write-Output "`file save successfully."              
  }
  catch
  {
    Throw $_.exception.message
  }
}
```

file is created after script run but it contains namespace("System.Xml.XmlDocument") only not file content.

I have also, tried to find out question related to my problem but most questiones are belong to read xml file from given path.

**Question :-**

1. How to pass xml file as parameter to powershell?(What I have did is it right?)
2. How to get that file in $txt(in powershell variable)? (I thing i am wrong here but i am not sure how to do that)
3. Is there any better way to do this?(best practices)

Answer (score 0):

1. Since you're getting the Namespace as the output, it looks like the document is making it to Powershell fine.
2. New-Item just calls the ToString method of the variable and sticks that into the file. For a lot of objects in Powershell, that's just the type or namespace of the object. Only really simple objects will actually output the way you expect. You should use the `.Save()` method within the XMLDocument type to export it properly. `Export-Clixml` is an option too.

   XMLDocument `.Save()`: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.xmldocument.save?view=netcore-3.1#System_Xml_XmlDocument_Save_System_String_

   Export-Clixml Docs: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/export-clixml?view=powershell-7
3. It's not detailed here why you're starting with C# and then switching to Powershell, but the two are very closely intertwined and `System.Xml.XmlDocument` is a .Net namespace that's accessible in both languages. Unless there is a necessary reason, it might be easier to keep all of this in just one language.